# PYSPARK: Find the penultimate (2nd largest value) row-wise

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am working out some Pyspark exercises and trying to write efficient and best practice code to be ready to work in a production environment.

Could use some feedback w.r.t.:

- Is the code structured well?
- Is the code efficient?
- Are there any other best practices I missed but should make habits of?

```
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Sample Data
data = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2", "col3"])


def penultimate(df, columns):
    df = (
        df
        # first define the biggest as the first column
        .withColumn("biggest", F.col(columns[0]))
        # initialize second largest as smallest possible number so it changes first iteration
        .withColumn("penultimate", F.lit(-math.inf))
    )
    for c in df.columns:
        df = (
            df
            # Swap biggest to second biggest when new biggest is found
            .withColumn(
                "penultimate",
                F.when(F.col("biggest") >= F.col(c), F.col("penultimate"))
                .otherwise(F.col("biggest"))
            )
            # Check if this column's value is larger, if so change biggest it to that value
            .withColumn(
                "biggest", 
                F.when(F.col("biggest") >= F.col(c), F.col("biggest"))
                .otherwise(F.col(c))
            )
            # Check if it is larger than the second largest (so far) but still smaller than the largest
            .withColumn(
                "penultimate",
                F.when((F.col("penultimate") < F.col(c)) & (F.col("biggest") > F.col(c)), F.col(c))
                .otherwise(F.col("penultimate"))
            )
        )
    return df

df = penultimate(df, df.columns)

df.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|Column1|Column2|Column3|biggest|penultimate|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|     10|     20|     30|   30.0|       20.0|
|     40|     60|     50|   60.0|       50.0|
|     80|     70|     90|   90.0|       80.0|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

## approach

> production environment

> structured well?

I would be reluctant to run this code in a production environment.
Some of it isn't due to the code at all -- it starts
with the chosen example.

We're using Spark, so by hypothesis we believe `df`
could have "many" rows, so many that we'd want to distribute
or partition them over cores and over hosts.
At which point I'm going to want to be able to reason
about *how* that is happening, and about locality of reference
for ordered rows.
So the thing I found missing in the example data was a
[PK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key#Design),
for example `student_id` corresponding to three math exam grades.

A smaller difficulty I had with the input data is that it is not
[tidy](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org).
I would find it more natural to work with
(student_id, date, exam_grade) rows.
That facilitates sorting, and it would readily accommodate
a student with four, or with just two grades.
The compound PK would be (student_id, date).

### sorting

```
F.lit(-math.inf)
```

I'm not crazy about using such sentinel values,
and try to avoid them where feasible.
Having initialized in that way,
now we have to worry about proving whether
the sentinel could ever leak out into the result.
Which could badly impact measures like AVG().

Drawing candidate return values from the input
is often preferable.

### shell game

The various .when() / .otherwise() clauses are
straightforward and they work.
But they are tedious, and not the sort of thing
where you can tell at a glance that it does what you meant
and all the corner cases are dealt with.

The biggest thing missing here is we should Extract Helper,
so a (testable!) function transforms a row, identifying the
penultimate value.
It would offer a natural refactoring point if later
requirements asked for largest, or 3rd largest, or median value.

Consider whether either of these obvious ways to find 2nd largest
might let you write a clearer helper function:

- Find max() of all values, filter it out, then report the new max().
- Sort() all values, verify there's more than one value, use index n-1 to report the penultimate.

Notice that these approaches immediately generalize to N columns.
Working with hardcoded three columns seemed odd,
given that the definition of "penultimate" doesn't care
about anything beyond "at least two values".

## test suite

After making an edit to your code (like adding `import math`), it
takes my laptop about thirty seconds to display revised results.
There's no need to fire up all the Spark machinery
just to test whether a little column sorter routine
is doing the right thing. Author one or more
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
to check both the "easy" cases you listed,
and also edge cases.
Notice that you can run such tests in a second or two,
leading to rapid edit-debug cycles.

## comments

I found your "Swap...", "Check...", "Check..." comments a little
bit helpful, and a little distracting.
Consider writing a single block of comments near the top,
outlining what will happen, and then let the code speak for itself.

When you feel the need to write comments in the middle of a function,
that suggests that the function is Too Long and you should Extract Helper,
which gives you the opportunity to informatively name the function.
Just pick out a few words from a comment sentence to create the function name.

## docstring

What I didn't see after `def penultimate`
was a """docstring""" explaining its
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
You don't *always* have to seize that opportunity,
but it is quite often that writing a single English sentence
will help you think more clearly about the code you're writing.

## type annotation

Annotations are optional.
But they carry wonderful documentation value:

```
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

def penultimate(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
```

And now e.g. `mypy` can automatically check whether
we accidentally returned `None`, or whether
caller accidentally passed in `None` or maybe an `int`.

I note in passing that the `df.penultimate` column
is of type `float`, unlike the other columns which
are all of integer type.
In most languages we can get away with handwaving
about "MAXINT will fit within a float, mostly".
Python's bigints have the unusual property that
they can blow out the IEEE double format,
so a large finite quantity winds up represented
as floating positive infinity.

Additionally, you have the opportunity to
leverage such annotations by tacking on a
[@beartype](https://pypi.org/project/beartype) decorator
if you're paranoid and want runtime enforcement of function
[contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

## redundant parameter

I have no idea why caller passes in `df` and `df.columns`.
Let `penultimate` pick out `df.columns` on its own.